# Coused by :org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot Maven Project and I'm trying to catch an IO Exception and I get this error:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'inventory.error' for locale 'de_DE'.
```

My method:

```java
@PostMapping("/inventory")
public String inventory(@ModelAttribute("Inventory") Inventory inventory, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    try {
        testBuildMdb();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("error", null, e.getMessage());
    }

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "inventory";
    }

    return "success";
}
```

I think this is because my windows language is German. How can I change my exception's language to English?

Comment: You don't nor shouldn't. You should have a default `messages.properties` containing the default (probably English) translations. It will use that as a fallback .

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space in Inventoryinventory?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the properties files cannot be found, based on properties file structure, the application.yml should be like spring.messages.basename: yourProjectDirectory/messages/messages